# Need a minimal Django data store example

Tags: android, python, django

I am new to Django. I am having difficulty to make a program to store the data.

I could not find any up-to-date example. So, Could you please post here or refer me to a minimal but complete example code.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The best you can do is go through django tutorial which covers all things you need to learn to accompish what you want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I have already covered that material. However, to save data in that tutorial , they use shell                                          >> from django.utils import timezone
>>> p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> p.save()...... I actually need to store my data into a database programmatically

Comment: Part 3 and 4 of this tutorial shows how to expose URL and define forms that will allow you to build a complete web application you need.

Answer (score 1):

Django-TastyPie with Android client

http://thecodachi.blogspot.com/2012/03/django-tastypie-with-android-client.html

http://thecodachi.blogspot.com/2012/04/django-tastypie-with-android-client.html

Comment: That part that is httpget, replace it with httppost.

Comment: OK, the data is going to come django side, at that time I will need a method to store the incoming data. Could you please help me out to write that method ?

Comment: You have to define the models in Django. See the official Django tutorial. 

Once that is set up, create the TastyPie resources related to the model (ModelResource). 

Each Resource has a corresponding Url that you use on Android.

When the Android app does a "POST" on the url (thru TastyPie), it will automatically save the data to the model for you.

Comment: I think I start to understand you a bit. Let's talk over an example that you recommend above.

Comment: class RecipeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
 queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'savedata'
allowed_methods = ['get', 'post'] Can you help me what should I add more ?

Comment: Yes. Then, create a ModelResource. Also make sure your database is set up.

Comment: So, [python manage.py syncdb] command sets up database, right ?